# Laravel5 regenerates CSRF Token across AJAX requests. Can't AJAX

Tags: ajax, angularjs, session, laravel, csrf

I'm working on an **API** built with Laravel5 and a **client** using Angular JS. Both are totally separated and independent.

To AJAX into the API, my **client** successfully requests for a token generated using Laravel's `csrf_token()` at a given endpoint (`/token`), which is then stored in its `$rootScope` to be later used as a **_token** field in every **POST** or **PUT** request.

But when sending an AJAX **PUT** or **POST** request, I get a **TokenMismatchException** error thrown.

I'm printing the token matched against in the ouput, and its a different one upon every AJAX request, but loading `/token` via browser (regular HTTP request), outputs the same token every time.

Any ideas what is going on here?

I don't know if this is by design and my app logic is flawed, or there is something else failing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the token to your header and include it in your ajax calls. Use

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

It's in the docs at

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: Both **headers** and **post** methods should work, none of them do. I've tried them both. The token is being passed to the API, it just doesn't match.